# How can I create a template with fields that is view only? [DocuSignApi]

Tags: docusignapi

I have a template that is configured with a recipient that has read only fields and only a signature control. The read only fields/tabs are populated in the view request my API sends to DocuSign to get the signature url. However I'd like to create a new duplicate template that does not have the signature control and is configured to only require the recipient to view the document. This way the only signature event that is set by DocuSign is "viewing_complete" and not "signing_complete" when they're done viewing the template/document.

Edit: The purpose of this is it gives the user a read only view of the template/document so they can catch any errors in the mapped fields/tabs to give them a chance to correct it before signing a final version.

Comment: Been a year this question has been posted, I am curious if you were able to figure out a way around this? I have a similar use-case and was wondering if you were able to achieve it using createEnvelopeRecipientPreview?

Comment: @HameezRizwan I haven't circled back to this to see if there is a better way now. I just created a duplicate template that doesn't have a signature configured in the tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you want to create this template from the API or from the web app.
You can easily do this from the web app and if you want to do from the API, you can [get a log of the API calls](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YJYTDcc7cZw) to see how it was done.
When you create a template from the web app, in the first screen, you can pick recipients and there's a drop down with different types of recipients:
[image]
Select the "**Needs to View**" recipient type for your needs.

Comment: I tried that but that doesn't allow mapping the tabs to the recipient. So when the view request is created, none of the data that is sent in the request is populated in the recipient view.

Comment: aha, I see now, yes, "Need to View" recipients cannot have tabs. You want tabs to update data, but you want to use a Needs To View, you cannot do this.

Comment: If it wasn't a template, I would suggest "pre-fill tabs", but these are not yet supported on templates.

Comment: You can try to see if you can do this via API, it may work, I didn't try it, but if you create it via API it may allow you to add tabs to "need to review" recipients. Worth a shot

Comment: Well that sucks. I'm also trying the `CreateEnvelopeRecipientPreview`, but that also isn't showing the tab data, just the underlying document.

Comment: if you make this a regular signer? what happens? does it not work either?

Comment: If I make them a regular signer it does work, but the callback query parameter is "signing_complete". The template is not configured with the Signature control and no signature ceremony occurred; they just previewed the data in a near identical template. What I'm looking for is a way to preview a template in a view only mode with the tabs populated so that the user only clicks "Close" and the response is "viewing_complete".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244089/discussion-between-marchwest-and-inbar-gazit).

Comment: Sorry, not sure there's something I can suggest for these requirements, except, perhaps, not to use tabs at all, but dynamically generate the document (where it's PDF, HTML or DOCX, there are libraries that allow you to modify the content dynamically)

Comment: Seems silly that there isn't a way to preview an envelope with tabs set.

Comment: Preview - yes, "need to view" no

Comment: Yeah I agree, I don't want/need to configure a "need to view", but that is just one of the options that seemed like it might've worked.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to configure a template to accept populated tabs for a recipient that is set as Needs to View or to preview an envelope recipient view and have the tabs populated, but not show the Signature control.